# How to create custom table programmatically(using code) without using installschema.php magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, table

> Actually I have created a custom grid in back-end for creating custom table there I am providing some fields like- table name, Assigned to Module Name, Number of Input text boxes. Now I want to generate table using Generate button.

Comment: You have to create table right?

Comment: @ChiragPatel,yes chirag

Comment: @hitesh balpande , please change the question title and content. Your target is created table programmatically  but your asked that how to  create   `InstallSchema.php using code` bother are different

Comment: @AmitBera,thanks

Comment: @hiteshbalpande you cannot create a file. please describe your question in details. what do you want to do after creating Installdata.php file? what is your goal?

Comment: @hi all,please check edited question,thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code in your file to create table.

```
protected $resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
)
{
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->createTable();
    $this->createTableSchema();
}

public function createTableCore()
{
    $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName('your_table_name');

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$tableName` (
     `config_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Config Id',
     `scope` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default' COMMENT 'Config Scope',
     `scope_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Config Scope Id',
     `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'general' COMMENT 'Config Path',
     `value` text COMMENT 'Config Value',
     PRIMARY KEY (`config_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH` (`scope`,`scope_id`,`path`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Your Comment'";

    $connection->query($sql);
}

public function createTableSchema()
{
    $setup = $this->resource;

    $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('your_table_name')
            )->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true]
            )->addColumn(
                'title',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255
            )->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT]
            )->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE]
            );

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}
```

You may choose your way.